# Can't access a second MYSQL database wih Java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Is there something specific to be aware of when connecting to a second MYSQL database in java?

I query one database `db1` just fine, but when i switch to a duplicate database`db2` and run the same query
When run in eclipse, the program just says "terminated"  with no output.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
    ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db2", "root", "password");
                    con.setReadOnly(true);
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

                    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("query that worked for db1");

    //then do stuff with res that printed out the grabbed 
//results successfully for db1`
```

Comment: without output? Maybe there is an empty catch block and you ignore some exception?

Comment: no the issue is that the code works perfectly for db1 but terminates when attempting to connect to db2.

Comment: Could you just post a working / runnable class? I mean with main method. I'd like to see your try and catch statements. Besides, what happens wehen you just write "foo" as your driver or JDBC connection string?

Answer (score 2):

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
// Load the JDBC driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
// Create a connection to the database
String serverName = "localhost";
String mydatabase = "db2";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName +  "/" + mydatabase; // JDBC url
String username = "root";
String password = "password";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
// Could not find the database driver
} catch (SQLException e) {
// Could not connect to the database
} finally {
System.out.println("Closing the connection.");
if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
}
```

Catch your exceptions and make sure that the Mysql drivers are on the classpath. Let us know for the exception messages you see so that we can address your question in a better manner.

Comment: Thanks...it just prints out "closing the connection" but does not execute any queries placed in the try block. Meanwhile it does so perfectly well for db1 that has the exact same tables as db2

Comment: Can you paste all your code here? Can you catch Exception as well? You can also debug this code to make sure connection is not empty. Also, do you close the connection for db1?

Comment: your example has empty catch clauses, and I would guess that's the reason for don't seeing the error.

Comment: I didn't fill-in the catch block..one can do whatever one needs to do once the exception is caught.

Answer (score -2):

May be is too simple, but you didnt say if you have close the previous connection to the db1 database, before establishing the new one to the db2 database.

Comment: I think he runs the program again, after changing the jdbc url. That would terminate all connections. Besides, it's no problem to have multiple connections to different databases open at the same time.